# Automatically add autoload

Tags: php, json, laravel, composer-php

I make a "HelperCommand" to generate helper in Laravel. "HelperCommand" will create a file in "app/Console/Commands/Helpers".

> php artisan helper:command time.php

```
public function handle()
{
    $name = $this->argument('name');
    File::put(app_path().'/Console/Commands/Helpers/'.$name, '');
}
```

I manually add file name in composer.json :

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Console/Commands/Helpers/time.php"
    ]
}
```

My question is how to automatically add autoload when generating helper?

thanks!

Comment: Depends, what do these files do? Are they php classes? Do they contain functions? Are they just data files?

Comment: Also, take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174024/composer-autoload-multiple-files-in-folder

Comment: This is php file php artisan helper:command time.php create a new file named time.php

Comment: Why should that be needed? Where is this file placed? Shouldn't the regular autoloader cover that namespace properly? Have you ever felt the need to add specific classes manually to that list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify `composer.json` in various ways.

#### Not recommended

One simple way is to use `file_get_contents ()` and `file_put_contents ()`.

```php
$composer = file_get_contents(base_path('composer.json')); // get composer.json
$array    = json_decode($composer, true);                  // convert to array

// Add new file
$array['autoload']['files'][] = $name;

// convert to json
$json = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);                               

file_put_contents(base_path('composer.json'), $json);      // Write composer.json
```

But, this way is **not effective**, and you lose a lot of time to update the autoloader, via :

```
composer dump-autoload
```

---

#### Recommendation

My advice, you should make your own composer package.

In your package service provider, you can get all helpers without update the autoloader.

```php
$files = glob(
    // app/Helpers
    app_path('Helpers') . '/*.php')
);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    require_once $file;
}
```

I am the owner of [`laravel-helpers`](https://github.com/Kristories/laravel-helpers). You can see the technique that I used there.

Comment: {"name":"laravel\/laravel","type":"project","description":"The Laravel Framework.","keywords":["framework","laravel"],"license":"MIT"..... how to make it pretty?

Comment: You can use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`. I will update my answer